# AppScript filter function not working for some values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

updated: I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns that i am concerned with:

Group (Ferrous/Non-ferrous/etc.)
RI No. (Unique identifier)
Supplier (Sellers of chosen RI No.) The flow of data happens like this: I select Group (say, Ferrous) --> In RI No. column, an automatic dropdown is created, showing RI Nos. of all items under Ferrous category show up --> I select a particular RI No. from this drop-down --> A drop-down of all sellers selling that item show up.
Now, I wrote a code which does this work perfectly, but it is unable make the list of Suppliers when I select an RI No. with a "-" in them. For example, from the RI No. list, if I select a value like "6181-1","Cu-18mm","CU-25x3","25_E.Cont","DOF", the Supplier drop-down list shoes zero options to choose from, even though it is expected to show 2 options for it. This problem does not occur for other values, like "6310-1" or even "TTK1 & TTK2" selected in the RI No. list.

Sample Spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xvz1NWiUqMWXik5k653slQhAXduwuQmq3_n0aJEhbRY/edit#gid=1605627126

Script:

````
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var wsopt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sorted items");
var opts = wsopt.getRange(2,1,wsopt.getLastRow()-1,13).getValues();
var firstlevelcolumn = 2;
var secondlevelcolumn = 5;
var thirdlevelcolumn= 6;
var wsopt2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("supplier details");
var opts2 = wsopt2.getRange(3,1,wsopt2.getLastRow()-1,12).getValues();


function onEdit(e)
{ var activecell= e.range;
  var val = activecell.getDisplayValue();
  var r= activecell.getRow();
  var c= activecell.getColumn();
  var wsName= activecell.getSheet().getName();
  if (wsName == "JPS")
  {
    if (wsName == "JPS" && c == firstlevelcolumn && r > 2)
    { applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);}
    if (wsName == "JPS" && c == secondlevelcolumn && r > 2)
    { applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);}
  }//JPS
  else if (wsName == "DDNI")
  {
    if (wsName == "DDNI" && c == firstlevelcolumn && r > 2)
    {applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);}
    if (wsName == "DDNI" && c == secondlevelcolumn && r > 2)
    { applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);}
  }//DDNI
}//close onEdiT

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r)
{
  if(val=== "")
    {
      ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else
    {
      ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
      var filteredopts = opts.filter(function(o){return o[0]===val});
      var listToApply = filteredopts.map(function(o){return o[1]});
      var cell=ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }//close else
}//close applyFirstLevelValidation

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r)
{
  if(val=== "")
    {
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else
    {
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
      var firstlevelcolvalue = ws.getRange(r,firstlevelcolumn).getDisplayValue();
      var filteredopts2 = opts2.filter(function(o){return o[6]===firstlevelcolvalue && o[4]===val});
      var listToApply2 = filteredopts2.map(function(o){return o[0]});
      var cell2=ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply2,cell2);
    }//close else
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell)
{
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
} ```
````

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your question sounds like you want to create _dependent drop-down lists_. Please edit the question and use that term to make it clear what you need. You may want to take a look at the [dependentDropDownLists_](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160451/269219) script. Note that it requires that the `GROUP`, `RI NO`and `SUPPLIER` columns are adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

I reviewed the code, and I was not able to find any issues with it. However, I made 2 copies to test, and in one of the copies I remove all the spaces in the "supplier details" from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

And that seems to fix the issue:
[image]

I'm guessing that the script cannot read the information properly when there are multiple spaces between the rows.

### Update:

I modified the code to see the values passed by your filter:

```
var filteredopts2 = opts2.filter(function(o){return o[6]===firstlevelcolvalue && o[4]===val});
```

And I noticed that the filter was comparing `Non Ferrouse` from the `JPS` tab with `Non- Ferrouse` in the `supplier details` tab.

[image]

After changing all the values from the `supplier details` from:

[image]

To:

[image]

The issue got fixed.

Comment: Hello Giselle! Thank you so much!! I am thrilled. This seems to have solved a big part of the trouble. However, the issue still persists for only some more items like "DOF", "25_E.Cont" from Non-Ferrous category. Could you please have a look?

Comment: let me check, I will review if there is any other reason why those are not working.

Comment: @Anushka, I updated the answer with the new information.

Comment: Giselle, thank you so so much for catching the overlook. Means a lot!

Comment: You are welcome @Anushka! I'm happy to hear that it's works for you now. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)